# Laravel 5.2 set model attributes based on fields in Input

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I have huge user update form. Sometimes update contains huge amount of fields, sometimes just one or two. This is my code:

```
public function updateUser(Request $request){
    $user = User::where('id',$request->id)->firstOrFail();

    if($request->first_name){
        $user->first_name= $request->first_name;
    }

    if($request->last_name){
        $user->last_name = $request->last_name;
    }

    if($request->job_name){
        $user->job_name= $request->job_name;
    }

    //etc.. 20 more fields

    $user->save();
```

It is possible to set model attributes dependent on fields in `$request`? Sometimes `$request` contains 1 field, sometimes 20. Please notice I want to **touch database only once**, using save() method at the end.

Comment: You mean set attributes automatically based on your request?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$user->update($request->all());
```

Make sure all necessary variables are specified in your `$fillable` array for `User` model

If you want to update model attributes without saving use `fill` method

Comment: Thanks for answer. However update() function causes updating the database. I want only to assign all parameters from request to model before touching database. Touching databse should be done at the end of script using save() method.

Comment: The method that You're looking for is `fill` https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fill

Comment: Amazing! this is exactly i was looking for. Can you please update answer so i can accept?

Answer (score 0):

If `$request` field name and `Model` field name are same(as it seems in your current code) try this:

`$input = $request->all();
$user = User::firstOrFail('id',$input->id);
$updateNow = $user->update($input);`

Another option is:

`DB::table('users')
            ->where('id', $request->id)
            ->update($request); //or can use Input::all()`

Have a look at it as well for more explanation: [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#updates)

Comment: Thanks for answer. However update() function causes updating the database. I want only to assign all parameters from request to model before touching database. Touching databse should be done at the end of script using save() method.

Comment: What other stuff you are doing before `save()` ?

Answer (score 0):

for **User** model

```
/**
* The attributes that are mass assignable.
*
* @var array
*/
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'facebook_id', 'job_name', '20 more fields...'
];
```

for **Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request){
    $allRequest = $request->all();
    // It is not in table
    unset($allRequest['_token']);
    User::create($allRequest);
}
```